# Can I copy a cross compiler tool chain between systems (I did before)?

Tags: ubuntu

I tested fairly extensively with Ubuntu 10.04 Beta 2 Server in a VM, and was able to simply copy (read  `tar x`) a cross compiled tool chain from an Ubuntu 8.10 VM.  I created the tar myself, which is essentially a lot of stuff in `\usr\local`.

Now that I've got a bare metal installation of Ubuntu 10.04 proper, the copy isn't working.  In particularly, I'm getting the error:

```
$ arm-linux-gcc
-bash: /usr/local/bin/arm-linux-gcc: No such file or directory
```

I've got the systems side by side in SSH windows ... any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you happen to switch to a 64 bit edition of Ubuntu 10.04?

If your VM was 32-bit and your real installation is 64-bit, you may still be able to get it to work by doing:

apt-get install linux32 ia32*

Comment: hmmm ... the *Ubuntu Server 10.04 Beta* was 64 bit, but the 8.10 VM wasn't.

Comment: Thats it, what a stress relief.  I'm am so grateful.  In two days, I'll assign a bounty and give you a hundred.